# Eliminar registros tipo datetime de una tabla de usuarios

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web que toma datos de un lector de huellas. Importo todos los registros a la BD de xampp y hasta ahí todo bien.

Cuando quiero evaluar las asistencias me encuentro con que hay 2 entradas.

Por ejemplo una es: `2018-03-05 08:50:30` y la otra `2018-03-05 08:50:52`. Esto pasa cuando ponen el dedo en el lector 2 veces.. Como puedo hacer para eliminar estos registros?

```
7,Enzo Rodriguez ,2018-02-22 17:34:28
7,Enzo Rodriguez ,2018-02-22 17:34:31

id,Nombre,fechaYHora(Datetime)
```